# Reading from text file and populate to Listbox with Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a window program where the program reads from a text file and display the data in a listbox. I have tried the below coding but the problem now is that every time I click on the button, it will append and the data will repeat.

How do I do it so that it reads the file and only include new input data?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\Outbound.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        // Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
        // the file is reached. 
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Listbox1.Items.Add(line);
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `Listbox1.Items.Clear()` once before reading the file?

Comment: Is there a way to refresh the list without using a button to run it ?

Comment: *Don't* try to modify the listbox directly. Both WinForms and WPF support data binding. 80% of WPF's functionality depends on data binding. You don't need ways to refresh the list, WPF will do it automatically if you use data binding

Comment: @JiaShin Sure, take a look at DispatcherTimer. If you want to read the file whenever it has changed, use a FileSystemWatcher.

Answer (score 4):

The probably most simple way to do what you want is to read all lines from the file into a collection, and then assign that collection to the ItemsSource property of your ListBox:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Listbox1.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Outbound.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Clemens said in comment, you can either `Listbox1.Items.Clear()` or `Listbox1.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Outbound.txt");`

But this would always replace all your listbox with the file. If you just want, as you said, to enter new data, you could simply check if `if(!Listbox1.Items.Contains(line))` before adding the item.

Depends on what you really want, **reupdate the whole list** or **just add new entries** and not removing old ones.

Comment: Checking `Items.Contains(line)` it probably not enough. Think about potentially deleted lines, you would have to delete the associated ListBox items.

Comment: Yes that's why I said : if he only wants to add new entries and leave old ones or some deleted from the file, I don't know the purpose of his program so it may be needed. Depends on what he wants as a behavior.

Comment: But then maybe I understood wrongly what he meant and then yes my answer is not what he needs